# Change model representation in Flask-Admin without modifying model

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have a model with a `__repr__` method, which is used for display in Flask-Admin.  I want to display a different value, but don't want to change the model.  I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702734/how-to-tell-flask-admin-to-use-alternative-representation-when-displaying-foreig), but that still requires modifying the model.  How can I specify a separate representation for Flask-Admin?

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    data = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<MyModel: data=%s>' % self.data
```

**Update**

File: models.py

```
class Parent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "parent"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    p_name = db.Column(db.Text)
    children = db.relationship('Child', backref='child', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Parent: name=%s' % self.p_name


class Child(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "child"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    c_name = db.Column(db.Text)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parent.id'))
```

File: admin.py

```
from flask.ext.admin import Admin
from flask.ext.admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from app import app, db
from models import Parent, Child


admin = Admin(app, 'My App')

admin.add_view(ModelView(Parent, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(Child, db.session))
```

When I try to create or edit "child" through admin panel, I see  representation from "Parent" class. I suppose it is because of relationship and I don't know how to redefine the representation for admin panel only.

Answer (score 1):

The following answers have helped me to solve my issue:

- [How to tell flask-admin to use alternative representation when displaying Foreign Key Fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702734/how-to-tell-flask-admin-to-use-alternative-representation-when-displaying-foreig)
- [Flask-admin, editing relationship giving me object representation of Foreign Key object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33698104/flask-admin-editing-relationship-giving-me-object-representation-of-foreign-key)
- [Flask-Admin Many-to-Many field display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417685/flask-admin-many-to-many-field-display/21423747)

The cause was in that I tried to replace `__repr__` with `__unicode__` instead just add `__unicode__` method.

But if anybody knows solution without modifying `models`, let me know and I'll add it here.

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass the model:

```
class MyNewModel(MyModel):
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<MyModel: DATA IS %d!>' % self.data
```

and then use `MyNewModel` instead of `MyModel`.

Comment: It was my first idea to make like this, but it doesn't work in my case, please see an update.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I've found this solve:

```
class Child(Parent):
def __repr__(self):
        return '<Child: name=%s' % self.p_name

setattr(Parent, '__repr__', Child.__repr__)
```

It overloads `Parent.__repr__`, but now you can not to change SQLA model.